# How to generate variable memory load (%) in linux?

Tags: linux, performance, stress-testing

I want to test performance of one of my other program with different memory load like 10%, 20%, 30% etc. To generate memory load , I used **stress** tool.

When I execute

```
stress -m 1 --vm-bytes 128M 
or
stress -m 1 --vm-bytes 256M
```

**top** command shows

```
% CPU      %Memory
99      5 - 10%
```

Maximum 10% memory load was generating, not exceeding any more.

**How to generate  20%, 30% memory load? 
Is there any other tool available for generating memory load in linux**

When I try to **restrict CPU utilization** using **cpulimit**, it doesn't change the CPU utilization.

```
cpulimit -p <pid>  -l 20
```

**Is it possible to restrict CPU utilization and memory load at the same time - like 10% CPU Utilization, 10% Memory, 10 % CPU Utilization, 50% Memory load ?**

I am using Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz,     Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS , 2GB RAM, 8 CPU core.